# ggplot2: remove and replace axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to plot a timeseries dataset by Julian Day but have the x-axis labels in Months (a much more informative interval). In the base plot function I know I would use `xaxt="n"` and `axis` but I can't figure out the ggplot equivalent.

Example:

```
temp <- c(8,10,9,12,15,16,22,12,5,4)
julian_day <- c(1,25,63,65,70,77,150,260,300,350)
temp_month <- c(1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12)
x <- data.frame(temp, julian_day, temp_month)

ggplot(x, aes(julian_day, temp)) + geom_line() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

I am able to plot by the correct variables and remove the x-axis but I can't figure out how to add an axis of `x$temp_month`

I tried adding `scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1:12), labels=c(1:12))` and/or `theme(axis.text.x = buoy_agg$month)` but neither worked.

I think it's just a matter of finding the right command. Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: check out [ggplot2 `labs()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labs.html) to add labels, like the axes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When plotting dates, I'd strongly recommend using `Date` class data and using `scale_x_date` - you can easily customize the axis with arguments to `scale_x_date` to show the month name, month abbreviation, month number, or any other date format.

Since you've got Julian day, I've converted that to date of an arbitrary non-leap year. As long as you don't label the year, that works for us to easily get the right month labels.

```
x$date = as.Date("2018-12-31") + x$julian_day

ggplot(x, aes(date, temp)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", name = "")
```

[image]

Switch `%b` to `%m` if you want month number rather than month abbreviation. See `?scale_x_date` for more options and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I normally do use the Date class but used Julian day in this case because the line represents the mean of many years of data (ie: just a month-day)  which I don't think works with Date class. I should have clarified.

Edit: OH! I see what you did by adding Julean day to an arbitrary day at the end of the year. Neat!

Comment: Edited a bit of that explanation into the answer to clean up the comments.